# Removing/Hiding Sensitive information in HTTP response

Tags: sharepoint, iis

I have created a site in Sharepoint services and hosted in IIS 6.0, the site is revealing few sensitive information like server name in the response. Please help me to secure or hide this information. The request and response is as given below (sensitive information is marked in bold lines).

Request –

```
GET /Finance/_layouts/userdisp.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: (Server IP)
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)
Connection: close
```

Response –

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 29 Jun 2011 00:08:33 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 12.0.0.6421
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Set-Cookie: WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated=443; path=/
Set-Cookie: MSOWebPartPage_AnonymousAccessCookie=443; expires=Wed, 29-Jun-2011 00:38:33 GMT; path=/
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 32318
```

Comment: this info may saves hackers time..

Comment: I presume you've done something about the "<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint">" etc. stuff in the page source too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide the Server Name reported in the headers by using URLScan:

http://www.iis.net/download/urlscan